# How would I replace characters in a string individually with corresponding integers?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

For some context, I have a long string of letters with corresponding integers (of which I have predefined as variable, i.e. X = 4), and I want to understand how to take this string and convert it to numbers *individually*.

I have a couple of inklings on how I would approach this, but each method I have tried didn't quite work out.

I have a long string made up of 5 different characters repeated randomly. How would I examine each of these characters individually and then create a corresponding string containing the corresponding numbers? I have thought of doing this as a list, but I don't know how I would automatically insert every single character as an item in the list, as there are hundreds of these characters.

Just to repeat, the letters must be independently reviewed and then given their number (which is pre-defined).

Examples inputs + outputs:

Input: `ASDF`

And, assuming

```
A = 1
S = 2
D = 3
F = 4
```

Output: `1234`

For more context, I would like to then add up all these numbers for a total.

Here's my code so far:

```
x = 10  # establishing roman numerals to integer conversion
l = 50
c = 100
d = 500
m = 1000

code = "LMXCDLMXDCLMXCDLMXDCLMXDCDXC"

code = code.replace(" ", "")  # get rid of spaces
'''
code = (" ".join(code))  # adding spaces between each character
'''
code = list(code)  # inserting each character as an individual in an array

print(code)
```

Comment: Without some example inputs and outputs, as well as possibly some attempted code, this is extremely unclear and likely too broad.

Comment: A statement like "but each method I have tried didn't quite work out." is worse than useless unless you plan on showing what you did and explaining how its differed from the expected.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Okay I will add some inputs and outputs now.

Comment: Show code. At least explain how the numbers are predefined.

Comment: How *exaclty* are the numbers predefined?

Comment: @JoeIddon Just with m = 8, like I showed at the top of my post. Am I doing something wrong? Would there be a better way of doing it?

Comment: @deckador Yes, see my answer, using a `dictionary` would be much more appropriate

Comment: Still unclear. Let's say `A=1; ...; Z = 26`. In that case `AZ` -> `126`. What sum do you expect to get: `1 + 26 = 27` or `1 + 2 + 6 = 9`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good point, I assumed the first way, but they could have meant the second!

Comment: What type do you expect `1234` to be? String or list? Please edit that into the question, which should be unambiguous without the comments.

Comment: Also, if this is homework, please note that (in the question as well). Provide the code you have attempted and explain why/how it did not work.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry that was example code, I'm clearly not doing this right so I'm gonna delete that stuff and just show you the code.

Comment: @deckador. That should always be your starting point. Part of the reason being that a coding problem is often caused by thinking about the problem incorrectly. In that case, a prose explanation will often be misleading, while a minimal code dump leaves no ambiguity.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for the advice, I will try and structure my posts in the future to include that fundamental piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have setup a `dictionary` for what each `character` translates to, i.e.:

```
d = {'a': 5, 'b': 9, 'c': 4, 'd': 2} #...
```

Then you can take a `string` such as:

```
s = "cabab"
```

And use a `list-comprehension` to get the corresponding `integer` for each `character` in the `string` from the `dictionary` and then `join` these together to form one complete `string` of `numbers`:

```
''.join(str(d[i]) for i in s)
```

which for our little example will give:

```
"45959"
```

I think this is what you wanted!

---

**Update**

Having seen your most recent edit, I see that you want the `sum`, that can be done in much the same way:

```
sum(d[i] for i in s)
```

which gives `32` for my example (`4` + `5` + `9` + `5` + `9`).

Comment: This looks very promising! I will try the code now and see if it gives me what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just completed the code and it works great! Thank you for explaining the dictionary feature, I wasn't aware of it until you pointed it out. Again, cheers, the code works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

For next time,try to include your code, or at least the important section of it. There is a help page somewhere.

My example of code is a=1,b=2,c=3, and outputs a string of numbers, but just use it as an example and do what you want to do.

```
end_string = ''
for letter in string:
    if letter=='a':
        end_string+='1'    
    elif letter=='b':
        end_string+='2'
    elif letter=='c':
        end_string+='3'
```

You can have an int "total" instead if you want a total.

If the letters have consecutive values (like in your ASDF case), you can do this:

```
first_val = 1
letters=['A','S','D','F']
result = ''
for letter in string:
   for set_letter in range(len(letters)):
        if letters[i] == letter:
            result += str(i+first_val)
```

Which will work for any length of array.

Comment: Sorry, I will do that next time and include it in an edit at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to manipulate your input as a string per-se but as a sequence of characters. If you are looking for the final sum, the output should be a list of integers, which you can then add up, not another string.

Another point is how you get the input mapping. The most convenient format is to use a dictionary for easy lookup. Instead of doing something like you have now, do the following:

```
# establishing roman numerals to integer conversion
conversion = {
    'x': 10,
    'l': 50,
    'c': 100,
    'd': 500,
    'm': 1000
}
```

You could do something like `conversion = locals()` to make the variable names into dictionary keys, but that would introduce a lot of invalid conversions.

If you have a dictionary, you can make a list of numbers from your string with a one-line dictionary comprehension:

```
code = "LMXCDLMXDCLMXCDLMXDCLMXDCDXC"
numbers = [conversion[c] for c in code if c in conversion]
```

The part `if c in conversion` will automatically skip any invalid characters like spaces in the string.

The sum can be computed using the builtin `sum` function:

```
total = sum(numbers)
```

If you don't need the intermediate list `numbers` for anything, you can compute the sum in one step:

```
sum(conversion[c] for c in code if c in conversion)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this.

```
// you could use 
map = dict(a=2, s=3, d=4, f=5)
print ''.join([str(map[k]) for k in "asdffdsa"])
```

Comment: Also, I have a feeling that this is not at all what OP is looking for, but the question is so vague, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: I did miss the python tag, but you could use the same logic using python regex